# How to get max matched string by using fuzzywuzzy in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to match string by using fuzzywuzzy library in python to get max possibility matches in the string.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

input_row = ['HINDUSTAN-CONSTRUCTION-COMPANY-LIMITED', 'HINDUSTAN-HOUSING-COMPANY-LIMITED']

matches = ['Akruti Group', 'Alps Entreprises', 'Amur real Estate Pvt Ltd.','Ansal Housing & Construction Ltd.','Vikas Construction','Jalaram Jagruti Developers Pvt. Ltd.', 'Hindustan Ltd']

data = []

for i in range(len(input_row)):

    data.append((fuzz.ratio(input_row[i], matches), input_row))

    print (max(fuzz.ratio(input_row[i], matches)))
```

Getting Error:

`TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Expected Output:

```
    String                                 best_matches, Percentage
'HINDUSTAN-CONSTRUCTION-COMPANY-LIMITED', 'Hindustan Ltd', 50
'HINDUSTAN-HOUSING-COMPANY-LIMITED', 'Hindustan Ltd', 65
```

Comment: What's the definition of `input_row`? I see it only beeing used in your code, but not set

Comment: @Rodolfo Donã Hosp, I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is incorrect. `fuzz.ratio` works with two strings and returns an int, you provide it `matches` which is a list of strings.

Additionally since your matches are substrings you may want to use partial_ratio instead of ratio to get the results you desire.

An example that should work:

```
for item in input_row:
    data = []
    for match in matches:
        data.append((item, match, fuzz.partial_ratio(match, item)))
    print (max(data, key=lambda x: x[2]))
```

### Improving results

#### Case

On the example you provided, there are bad matching result for `'Hindustan Ltd'` . You might want to make a case-insensitive comparison by using `lower` on both strings

#### Nouns

Some nouns like `"Construction"` are long and common in your dataset, which make for example `'Vikas Construction'` score better than `'Hindustan Ltd'` for `'Hindustan Construction'`. If the number of nouns is small, a good way to reduce this is to use a dictionnary to reduce similarity :

`shorthands = {'construction':'ctt', 'limited': 'ltd', 'housing': 'hsg'}`
Then replace it in both strings

```
...
for match in matches:
    for k, v in shorthands.items():
        match_lower = match.lower().replace(k, v)
        item_lower = item.lower().replace(k, v)
    data.append((item, match, fuzz.partial_ratio(match_lower, item_lower)))
...
```

Comment: can you please explain `key=lambda x: x[2])` ?

Comment: @user10600066 `data` contains a list of tuples, in order to compare them between each other we have to provide a comparison key. A comparison key is a function which takes an element and returns a number. In our case, this is the 3rd column, containing the ratio. Additional details for `key` and `lambda` in the official Python documentation

Comment: Is there any other way to match the string? because fuzzy is not giving the correct result? please let me know, I have multiple names and want to match with probability percentage.

Comment: @user10600066 ok, I updated my answer with some way you could go. To go further this would be a code review, as we would speak about improving working code.

Answer (score 0):

`ratio` function returns an integer, and `max` expects an iterable (to calculate the maximum iteration), changing the line with the `max` call for a list comprehension should print it:

```
print(max(fuzz.ratio(input_row[i], j) for j in matches))
```

Although, to print your expected output it would be a better fit to use `extractOne` from `process` module, which extracts the most similar string:

```
for word in input_row:    
    print(word+', ', ', '.join(map(str,process.extractOne(word, matches))))
```

As a side note, I also changed the for loop because there's no need to iterate on the indexes, you can iterate directly trough the words

Comment: getting error: TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list. here - `print(word+', ', ', '.join(map(str,process.extractOne(word, matches))))`